# Evaluate Left And Right Limits Of $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\cos2x}}$ At $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Evaluate Left And Right Limits Of $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\cos2x}}$ At $0$

The graph of $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\cos2x}}$ appears to have a jump discontinuity at $0$ and I want to calculate the left and right limits of $f(x)$ to show there is a discontinuity at $0$.

[image]

I can't figure out how to manipulate the function in order to give different left and right limits.

Here's one of my attempts at trying to manipulate the funtion in to something more familiar to me:

$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\cos2x}}$
(divide numerator and denominator by $(2x)^2)$

$ =\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{x}{4x^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{-(\cos2x-1)}{2x}}}$

$= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{4x}}{\sqrt{\frac{-(\cos2x-1)}{2x}}}$

Now I was thinking that I can apply $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos(\theta)-1}{\theta} =0$ but it doesn't help me at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A start:** Use $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2 x$. One needs to be careful when finding the square root of $2\sin^2 x$. It is $\sqrt{2}|\sin x|$.

Comment: I managed to solve it using your hint. How did you know to go that direction?

Comment: Variants of $1-\cos 2x$ come up pretty often. An alternative is to use the series expansion of $\cos 2x$, but that involves material covered somewhat later.

Comment: I've not yet come across a problem that needed that variation of $\cos 2x$, unfortunately. Could it have been reasoned that one should try and get some expression in the denominator of the form $\sqrt{(some\, expression)^2} = |some\, expression|$ since one is calculating a double-sided limit(which requires two separate(possibly different) equations for each side of $x$)? Is that something you've looked for before?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach would be to multiply by $\sqrt{1+\cos 2x}$ on the top and bottom to get

$\;\;\;\displaystyle\frac{x\sqrt{1+\cos2x}}{\sqrt{1-\cos^{2}2x}},$  and then use the identities $1-\cos^{2}\theta=\sin^{2}\theta$ and $\sqrt{t^2}=|t|$

to simplify the denominator.

(Notice that this method will work for $\cos nx$ for any integer $n\ge1$.)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\sin x}}{x} = 1$$

$$\displaylines{
  1 - \cos \left( {2x} \right) = 2\sin ^2 x \cr 
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{{\sqrt {1 - \cos \left( {2x} \right)} }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{{\sqrt {2\sin ^2 x} }} \cr 
   = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{{\sqrt 2 \left| {\sin x} \right|}} \cr 
   = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 \frac{{\left| {\sin x} \right|}}{x}}} \cr}
$$
$$
 \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0^ +  } \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 \frac{{\left| {\sin x} \right|}}{x}}} =  + \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }} \\ 
 \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0^ -  } \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 \frac{{\left| {\sin x} \right|}}{x}}} =  - \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }} \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$